# root cannot delete a directory from a user named admin

Tags: linux, directory, root

I can not delete this directory `admin` when under the root permission. Can anyone help?
This is mainly due to the improper uninstall of the Vesta control panel. And the file attributes are shown here:

```
-------------e- admin/conf/mail 

-------------e- admin/conf/web

-------------e- admin/conf/dns
```

and the attributes for directory admin are:

```
----i--------e- admin/conf
```

Comment: If the folder cannot be removed, it may be locked for some other reason than permissions.  Like, it might still be in use.  You could try booting up under some other version of Linux (like a live USB or something), and delete the folder that way.  Of course, that might cause errors later.  But at least you'll know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the attribute `i` is causing problems, that attribute means the file is immutable.

With files like this not even root can change them, you need to change permissions first and then try to delete.

if you have a ext2, 3 or 4 filesystem you can use the `chattr` command to change the attribute.

Try executing the command:

`>sudo chattr -i {filename}`

This commands removes the attribute, and you should be able to delete the files.

If you want to set this bit to another file, is a trick to secure some files from deletion even from root, you can try:

`>sudo chattr +i {filename}`

Comment: This helps change the file attribute to: drwxr-x--x 2 root root
but I still cannot delete the file even under root